# Passing json parameters to rails api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using jquery's .ajax method to make a get call to ruby on rails api.  The body of get call includes a boolean variable.  However this boolean variable keeps getting converted to string on rails side.  I'm using correct contentType when making the request.

Here is my javascript ajax call:

```
                var postBody = {male: true}
                var request = $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "/biographies/getAll",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: postBody
            });
```

On Ruby on rails controller side, I'm using:

```
params[:male]
```

However params[:male] returns "true" string instead of true boolean.

According to Ruby on Rails api:

> If the "Content-Type" header of your request is set to "application/json", Rails will automatically convert your parameters into the params hash, which you can access as you would normally.
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters

Does anyone has any idea why it would not convert json request to boolean but keep it as string.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails, parameter values are **always strings**; **Rails makes no attempt to guess or cast the type.** You have to modify your code logic to adjust with this Rails behaviour. e.g.:

```
params[:male] == 'true'
```

See [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters) for reference.

Comment: That seems to be ok but i think json allow booleans and so there should be some way to keep it as boolean

Comment: Even though the original value is boolean, when it passed as a Rails params, it becomes a string and is processed by the Rails controller and in the controller side, `params[:male]` will always be string. If you know how to keep it as boolean, please let me know, I would learn something new then :)